# CFString release, why only on ipad?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, instance, cfstring

I have the same project, that at the beginning, it worked also on ipad, but now it works only on iphone devices, not ipad ones. It's a project iphone/ipad compatibile.

Probably i edit something but i don't know how!

The returned error in DEBUG || RELEASE mode on ipad DEVICE was the classic:

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x110500
```

...but on iphone, it's all ok.

I can't able to debugging because it show me only assembly code and i don't know where is the issue...

Is this problem appened around? It's my problem or ipad issue?
What could be different on these devices?

thanks, alberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you're linking against an older version of the frameworks on the iPhone and a newer version on the iPad.  If the older version was inadvertently leaking a string, it's likely that the leak was fixed in a newer version of the framework.

At any case, it ultimately means that you're not managing your memory correctly.  Any time you see "message sent to deallocated instance", it means you've under-retained or over-released an object.  Search this site for how to use `NSZombieEnabled` (or the Zombies tool in Instruments).  Those answers will give you the best information on how to track down the source of the bug. :)

Comment: thanks, NSZombieEnabled was already enabled. Now i disabled it and my app works with this error: "*** __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(): release of previously deallocated object (0x15f480) ignored". any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
It was a stupid `NSString release`.
Now is fixed, but **this problem occurs only on ipad**! :) don't know why!

thanks.